# Rails select rows from a table where a related table's all rows have a certain value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Basically I have 3 tables. Ignore the syntax. I just wanted to show the idea.

```
ModelA:
    belongs_to :ModelB

ModelB:
    has_many: ModelA
    has_and_belongs_to_many :ModelC

ModelC
    has_and_belongs_to_many :ModelB
```

How can I get all the rows from ModelA where all rows of ModelC have flag = 'Y'?
I've tried:

```
ModelA.joins(:ModelB => :ModelC).where("#{ModelC.table_name}.flag = 'Y'")
```

and dozen other ways without success. I know the code above doesn't check all the rows, but that's as far as I've got. I would prefer using ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

Their is a solution which will solve your problem but its not a perfect one

```
ModelA.all - ModelA.joins(:ModelB => :ModelC).where("#{ModelC.table_name}.flag != 'Y'")
```